# Alertview click to UITableviewcontroller

Tags: uialertview

am new to iphone programming. I have a viewcontoller with an alertview in it. When the ok button on alertview is clicked it takes to another UITableviewcontroller. I am able to get my cells with objects in it. but am unable to get the navigation bar on top. please tell me y is it so?

thanks
viki

Comment: Could you present some generic code?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 
 tablelistcardamage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tablelistcardamage addObject:@"Glass only damage"];
 [tablelistcardamage addObject:@"Accident damage"];
 [tablelistcardamage addObject:@"Fire"];
 [tablelistcardamage addObject:@"Theft"];
 [tablelistcardamage addObject:@"Weather"];
 
 [self setTitle: @"Car Damage"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: only these objects are displayed in tableview. how to get the navigationbar displayed. Its a UITableviewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex == 1){
        Accidenthelpercall* help = [[Accidenthelpercall alloc]initWithNibName:@"Accidenthelpercall" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:help animated:YES];
        [help setTitle:@"Accident Helper"];
        [help release];
    }

    if(buttonIndex == 2)
        {               
            Accidentdamagecar* damagecar = [[Accidentdamagecar alloc]initWithNibName:@"Accidentdamagecar" bundle:nil];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:damagecar animated:YES];
                    [damagecar setTitle: @"Car Damage"];
                    [damagecar release];

        }
}
```